# How to implement a mapped keyword match with multiple keywords and preference based on number of hits?

Tags: php, mysql

Background: I'm trying to use a popular "standard" medical coding system that provides a pre-made "keyword" table, using a well-defined mapping.

Simplified, basically it takes every word in the text description and maps it to a shorter, normalized keyword, like so:

Data records
id : desc

```
* 10 : Gonkulator-2500 image reconstruction
* 11 : DICOM image upload
* 12 : SpiffyCont Image Interface
```

Would be mapped to a keyword index like so:

keyword : rec_id

```
* GONKU : 10
* IMAGE : 10
* RECON : 10
* DICOM : 11
* IMAGE : 11
* UPLOA : 11
* SPIFF : 12
* IMAGE : 12
* INTER : 12
```

The easiest (to code) way to deal with this would obviously be to simply map the user search input to the keywords the same way and do an AND query.

What I'm looking for, though, is something to improve usability by being able to return partial matches so that the user who gets confused and searches for "Gonkulator-2500 image upload" doesn't get a blank result, but the "closest hits"

```
* Gonkulator-2500 image reconstruction (66%)
* DICOM image upload (66%)
* SpiffyCont Image Interface (33%)
```

So near as I can figure, I need results on the order of record_id:matches

```
* 10: 2
* 11: 2
* 12: 1
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts or pointers on how to do it, but lectures on database normalization should more properly be directed to the various international standards orgs. :)

Update: I forgot to mention (and I had intended to. FFB syndrome strikes again) that my first thought was a subquery:

```
SELECT rec_id, count(keyword) as matches 
    FROM ( 
         SELECT keyword, rec_id FROM index_tbl 
         WHERE keyword = 'KEY1'  OR keyword = 'KEY2' OR ...etc
     )
GROUP BY rec_id;
```

but ISTR that mysql doesn't exactly handle sub-queries well, especially on huge tables (1M+ records). Which is to say, it soils itself, then chokes and dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you did not forgot to put indexes on the tables? Actually (unless I am not missing something) you do not need a subquery here.

```
SELECT rec_id, count(keyword) as matches FROM index_tbl WHERE keyword = 'KEY1' ... GROUP BY rec_id;
```